# how to tokenise a word using java API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to divide a word into tokens. for example I searched for word "lunchbox". I want to divide it into "lunch", "box" using JAVA.

```
String name = "lunchbox";
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(name, "^\\s*\\S+\\s*$");
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());
    }
```

I tried this but did not work.
I also want to know whether I can achieve this using elastic search.

Comment: Get a dictionary of the single words and split by a lookahead pointing at either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Elasticsearch to tokenize your words in a custom way, you can use a Custom Analyzer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using ElastichSearch, you can easly use the API provided by Lucene. For example, the following piece of code shows the usage of a `LetterTokenizer` which  is a tokenizer that divides text at non-letters.

```
TokenStream tokenStream = new LetterTokenizer(new StringReader(document.trim()));
CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = tokenStream
        .addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
tokenStream.reset();

while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
    String string = charTermAttribute.toString();
    //Do something with your string
}
tokenStream.close();
```

You could further investigate Lucene API in order to find the right Analyzer for your purpose.